# Games with Gold on Xbox One only?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I have recently just renewed my Xbox Gold on my 360, so I can play some old games with friends. And I noticed that they still had "Games With Gold" offers running. This month the free game was Defense Grid 2, but it mentioned it was on Xbox One.

Are all of these "free" game offers one Xbox One, or can I play them on my Xbox 360?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each month there are four free Games With Gold games, it used to be that two were for Xbox 360 only and two were for Xbox One only, but with the introduction of backwards compatibility on Xbox One, [every Xbox 360 game is now playable on Xbox One as well](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/xbox-live-membership/games-with-gold-faq).

Defense Grid 2, which you specifically mentioned, is an Xbox One only game.

For future reference, the easiest way to find out which games are playable on which console is by going to the [Games With Gold](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/games-with-gold) website.

Comment: @Timelord64 Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Timelord64 All of the Xbox 360 Games For Gold releases going forward are on the Xbox One backwards compatability list meaning they are all playable on Xbox One. You will, however have to go to the website to "purchase" them and from there they'll show up in your Xbox One library.

Comment: @Timelord64 Excuse me for that, I forgot that they recently allowed you to download the Xbox 360 games directly from your Xbox One now. Here's your source you asked for: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/xbox-live-membership/games-with-gold-faq

Answer (score -1):

As stated by other users, games designed for Xbox One only work on Xbox one, while new gold games designed for Xbox 360 will work on Xbox one as of some time last year.

All new Xbox 360 releases for 'games for gold' would be guaranteed to work with Xbox One, so be sure to click the download link on the Xbox One games as well, as you are not only entitled to the games released for your console, but all the free offerings for that month. If you fail to click that download button, you will miss out on it.

Alternativley, if you decide to get an Xbox One in the future, you will immediately have a library of games to play from previous redeemed 'games for gold' Xbox One titles. Of course, you will have to look at your games list online to remind you of all the games, and go online to actually download the content for the Xbox One when you get it.

But if your question is if you get a game that is released on gold that is designed for xbox one but also has a title which is the same substantial game for xbox one on the 360 as is this month with goat simulator you do not get the 360 version of goat simulator just because you have the xbox one version.

Comment: This is just a duplicate answer. If you do not have anything new to add, simply upvote the original answer to confirm it.

Comment: If you think your addressing content that was not mentioned by tcjohnson you should make it more clear. As it stands, this answer has some poor formatting issues when compared to the standards of Arqade. I can fix the poor format, but you havnt made it clear what additional information you provide *in context of the question*.

Comment: I have fixed the spelling and general format discrepancies. For future reference, we take spelling and grammar seriously. Noones perfect, so a little will slide, and most of the time, users will edit corrections for you. But to a degree, failure to use basics *can* be interpreted as a lack of effort. Things like capitals at the start of a sentence, and not using abbreviations.

Comment: I have a tendency to dislike changing a users answer to remove inaccuracies, but **not all games for 360 run on the xbox one**. Only supported games will be released through games for gold, but to say "all games designed for xbox 360 will run on xbox one" is misleading. It might also be important to note that you have to actually *purchase* the game to acquire it (during GfG the price will be "$0.00"). The download interface comes *after* the initial purchase, at which point the game has been purchased to your account and is yours, but you do not have to physically download the game.

Comment: Having literally just purchased both 360 and Xbox One titles to clarify the exact process, I can actually confirm that "Download" comes **before** purchasing the game to your account, on Xbox 360. So yeah. I don't really see the additions you mention, but if you address the inaccuracies I might consider at least removing my down-vote.